# Group data by timeframe on a datetime Highcharts graph

Tags: highcharts

Consider the following series:

```
[
    {
        "x": 1447840800000,
        "y": 199214,
        "num_messages": 6
    },
    {
        "x": 1447842600000,
        "y": 27152,
        "num_messages": 3
    },
    {
        "x": 1447844400000,
        "y": 349919,
        "num_messages": 7
    }
    ...
]
```

Each of the timestamps are a half-hour apart. I'm currently showing 2-weeks worth of data like this on a datetime-formatted Highcharts column chart. I would like to give users the ability to view it in different increments of time, not just the default half-hour. When larger increments are chosen, the `y` and `num_messages` values should be summed for whichever data points fall within a given increment.

Currently, I am manipulating the series array manually to create a new series with the desired time increments. But can Highcharts essentially do this for me? Tried googling and looking through the API but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: This does not involve Highstock, correct? It has some more "grouping" features than Highcharts.

Comment: Correct. I had a brief hopeful moment when researching the issue before realizing that I was on the Highstock API :)

Comment: If you need a grouping of data, then [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.line.dataGrouping) would be a solution, but this is a Highstock-only feature (Highcharts doesn't have it). However, it is possible to create a Highcharts chart using highstock.js library and enable `dataGrouping` - simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/2jjbLy2a/

Comment: @KacperMadej I can't use the Highstocks library for this, but good to know!